# SQL: SUM of Each Department

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

There are 4 Departments: 10, 20, 30 and 40.

I need to get the SUM of the salaries of Dept10, 20, 30 and 40.

This is what I want to get:

```
+------+--------------+
| Dept | Sum salaries |
+------+--------------+
|   10 |            5 |
|   20 |            3 |
|   30 |            6 |
|   40 |            8 |
+------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please provide us: the table structure, example data and how you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: different query may provide the same result as you want depending on the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Dept, SUM(salaries)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Dept;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!